# Visual Studio c# Error CS7036 Method Call

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, call

I keep getting the CS7036 error in Visual Studio and I cant figure out how to correct it. the error code CS7306 occurs in the eROISImport.GenerateRport(); call. I'm not sure what parameters it wants since in the GenerateReport method creation at the top the parameters are defined. I have tried to define the parameter in the eROISIMPORT.GenerateReport but it is not accepted when I use the totalApplied or any others parameters that are defined in the GenerateReport method. Another issue I get is in the GenerateReport method I get the CS0051 Inconsistent accessibility parameter type List. This error occurred when I changed private static to public void. I appreciate any help with this.

```
 public void GenerateReport(int totalUnknown, int totalApplied, int totalAccepted, int totalRejected, int totalDropped, int totalTesting, int totalNonCompliance, int totalNoncompliance8453, int totalNoncomplianceFieldMonitoring, int totalRevoked, List<DataInput>dataInputList)   

    public static Main(string[] args)
    {
        EROIRSImport eROIRSImport = new EROIRSImport();


        eROIRSImport.ImportFile(args);
        eROIRSImport.GenerateReport();
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: If the `GenerateReport` method that you've posted is really the one you're trying to call, then the method needs 11 parameters, and you're passing it zero.

Comment: @gunr2171, I edited the code down to what is actually causing the error. In the eROISIMPORT.Generate call I have tried to put in int, and the parameter name but then I get the not defined in scope error message. What would I put in that method call to clear the error?

Answer (score 1):

> I get the CS0051 Inconsistent accessibility parameter type `List<DataInput>`. 
> This error occurred when I changed `private static` to `public void`

That means `DataInput` isn't `public`.

A method can't expose (as a parameter or a return type) a type that is less accessible than the method itself, because consuming code won't be able to use the method if they can't know the types it exposes.

Either change `DataInput` to also be `public` or change the accessibility of the method to match the accessibility of `DataInput`.  (`internal`?  `private`?)

Comment: Pardon the question but now that method is set to public shouldnt that clear up the accessibility issue?

Comment: @software_dev_1: According to the description in the question, that's precisely what *caused* the accessibility issue.  If a method is `public` then any type exposed by that method also needs to be `public`.